# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation') Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting undefined is not an object evaluating _this.props.navigation. Here is my code. I want to use Flatlist to call the screen 'PlaceorderScreen.js' number of times from the component 'NearbyLSP.js' present in the 'HomeScreen.js'. Also I had referred many solutions for the above problem but yet I didn't get how to get through it. I am a beginner in react-native, So I had used expo for app development.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    SafeAreaView,
    TextInput,
    Platform,
    StatusBar,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions,
    Animated,
} from "react-native";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import Category from './Category'
import Expressmode from './Expressmode'

import { FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import NearbyLSP from "./NearbyLSP";

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

const data = [
    {id:'1',name:'LSP1',phone:'1234',email:'abc@gmail.com'},
    {id:'2',name:'LSP2',phone:'0234',email:'abc2@gmail.com'},
    {id:'3',name:'LSP3',phone:'2234',email:'abc3@gmail.com'}
]

const renderList = ((item) =>{
    return <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} 
                activeOpacity={0.7}>
                <NearbyLSP name={item.name}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
})  


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)

        this.startHeaderHeight = 80
        this.endHeaderHeight = 50
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
            this.startHeaderHeight = 100 + StatusBar.currentHeight
            this.endHeaderHeight = 70 + StatusBar.currentHeight
        }

        this.animatedHeaderHeight = this.scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 50],
            outputRange: [this.startHeaderHeight, this.endHeaderHeight],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
        })

        this.animatedOpacity = this.animatedHeaderHeight.interpolate({
            inputRange: [this.endHeaderHeight, this.startHeaderHeight],
            outputRange: [0, 1],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
        })
        this.animatedTagTop = this.animatedHeaderHeight.interpolate({
            inputRange: [this.endHeaderHeight, this.startHeaderHeight],
            outputRange: [-30, 10],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
        })
        this.animatedMarginTop = this.animatedHeaderHeight.interpolate({
            inputRange: [this.endHeaderHeight, this.startHeaderHeight],
            outputRange: [50, 30],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Animated.View style={{ height: this.animatedHeaderHeight, backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#dddddd' }}>
                        <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row', padding: 10,
                            backgroundColor: 'white', marginHorizontal: 10,
                            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
                            shadowColor: 'black',
                            shadowOpacity: 0.2,
                            elevation: 1,
                            marginTop: null
                        }}>
                            <Icon name="ios-search" size={25} style={{ marginRight: 10 ,marginTop:5 , opacity:0.6}} />
                            <TextInput
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                placeholder="Find LSP"
                                placeholderTextColor="grey"
                                style={{ flex: 1, fontWeight: '700', backgroundColor: 'white' }}
                            />
                        </View>


                    </Animated.View>
                    <ScrollView
                        scrollEventThrottle={16}
                        onScroll={Animated.event(
                            [
                                { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } }
                            ]
                        )}
                    >
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white', paddingTop: 20 }}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                Laundry Service Provider Type
                            </Text>

                            <View style={{ height: 130, marginTop: 20 }}>
                                <ScrollView
                                    horizontal={true}
                                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                                >
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} activeOpacity={0.7}><Category  name="Dry Clean" /></TouchableOpacity>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} activeOpacity={0.7}><Category  name="Iron"/></TouchableOpacity>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} activeOpacity={0.7}><Category  name="Dry Clean + Iron" /></TouchableOpacity>
                                </ScrollView>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 40}}>
                                <Text style={styles.text}>
                                    Find Nearby LSP
                                </Text>
                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: '100', marginTop: 10,paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
                                    Verified LSP Providers
                                </Text>
                                <View style={{ marginTop: 20, paddingHorizontal: 15
                                 }}>
                                    <FlatList
                                        data={data}
                                        renderItem={({item})=>{
                                            return renderList(item)
                                        }}
                                        keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
                                        navigation={this.props.navigation}
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                Express Mode
                            </Text>
                            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20, marginTop: 20, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                <Expressmode width={width}
                                    name="LSP1"
                                    type="Dry Clean"
                                    price={82}
                                    rating={4}
                                />
                                <Expressmode width={width}
                                    name="LSP2"
                                    type="Iron + Dry Clean"
                                    price={82}
                                    rating={4}
                                />
                                <Expressmode width={width}
                                    name="LSP3"
                                    type="Iron"
                                    price={82}
                                    rating={4}
                                />


                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>

                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
    );
        ;
    }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 24, 
        fontWeight:'700', 
        paddingHorizontal: 20 
    }

});
```

'HomeScreen.js' contains another component where I had successfully used the navigation to navigate to 'PlaceorderScreen.js'. But when I call this navigation inside Flatlist it gives the error.

NearbyLSP.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { Card } from "react-native-paper" ;
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

export default class NearbyLSP extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Card style={styles.mycard}>
                    <View style={{ width: width - 40, height: 200}} >
                        <Image
                            style={{ flex: 1, height: null, width: null, resizeMode: 'cover', borderRadius: 5, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#dddddd' }}
                            source={require('../assets/a.jpeg')}
                        />    
                        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                </Card>

            </View>

        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mycard: {
        margin: 5
    }
});
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator , createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import LoadingScreen from "./screens/LoadingScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import SignupScreen from "./screens/SignupScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import AboutScreen from "./screens/AboutScreen";
import PastorderScreen from "./screens/PastorderScreen";
import TrackScreen from "./screens/TrackScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import PlaceorderScreen from "./screens/PlaceorderScreen";
import MapsScreen from "./screens/MapsScreen";
import NearbyLSP from "./screens/NearbyLSP";
import { Ionicons , MaterialIcons } from  '@expo/vector-icons';

import * as firebase from "firebase";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAhwjD3jodBg6JGJ7Oo72r7-m2T5wwPaUg",
    authDomain: "a4project-2d896.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://a4project-2d896.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "a4project-2d896",
    storageBucket: "a4project-2d896.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "181932238433",
    appId: "1:181932238433:web:aa3f6fa3947976a8352c20",
    measurementId: "G-SW6N6N8JYK"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    NearbyLSP:NearbyLSP,
    PlaceOrder:PlaceorderScreen
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        title:'Home',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'#12B2C2',
        },
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
    }
})

const OrderStack = createStackNavigator({
    Order: TrackScreen,
    Maps: MapsScreen,
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        title:'Orders',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'#12B2C2',
        },
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
    }
})

const PastorderStack = createStackNavigator({
    Pastorder: PastorderScreen,
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        title:'Pastorder',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'#12B2C2',
        },
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
    }
})


const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
    About: AboutScreen
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        title:'Profile',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'#12B2C2',
        },
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
    }
})




const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Signup: SignupScreen
},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor:'#12B2C2',
        },
        headerTintColor:'#fff',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontWeight:'bold'
        }
    }
})

const myTabs= createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home:HomeStack,
    Orders:OrderStack,
    Profile:ProfileStack,
    Pastorder:PastorderStack

},
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation })=> {
        return {
            tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>{
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let myicon
                if(routeName=="Home"){
                    myicon='md-home'
                    return <Ionicons name={myicon} size={30} color={tintColor}/>
                }else if(routeName=="Profile"){
                    myicon='md-person'
                    return <Ionicons name={myicon} size={30} color={tintColor}/>
                }else if(routeName=="Orders"){
                    myicon='md-book'
                    return <Ionicons name={myicon} size={30} color={tintColor}/>
                }else if(routeName=="Pastorder"){
                    myicon='library-books'
                    return <MaterialIcons name={myicon} size={30} color={tintColor}/>
                }

            }
        };
    }
});

export default createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            Loading: LoadingScreen,
            Auth: AuthStack,
            App: myTabs
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: "Loading"
        },

    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code within FlatList of 'HomeScreen.js' is modified as follows

```
<FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={this.rendeList}
      keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
  />
```

and the renderList function which was outside the class component is transferred inside and modified as

```
renderList = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} 
                activeOpacity={0.7}>
                <NearbyLSP name={item.name}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      };
```

Due to transferring the renderList function inside the class component, it gets access to the this.props and it can be used for navigation to new screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just writing `navigation={this.props.navigation}` in Flatlist won't let you navigate to the desired screen. You have to create a Touchable component in the Flatlist and add the navigation logic into the onPress logic of this Touchable Component.

`this.props.navigation` is a collection of data and methods, if you need to navigate through screens you need to use `this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')}` instead, this is the method that does the navigation for you. You can `console.log(this.props.navigation)` to understand better.

Refer to how navigation is implemented in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407626/8851276

Comment: I had tried your above solution in  'renderList ' method in HomeScrren.js . Also I tried by changing the navigation={this.props.navigation} to navigation={this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} . But Still it prompts the same error.

Comment: Also I had used same  inside `<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} activeOpacity={0.7}><Category  name="Dry Clean" /></TouchableOpacity>` in 'HomeScreen.js' where I had successfully navigated to 'PlaceOrder.js' . But it isn't happening inside the FlatList and prompting the error

Comment: I had removed the navigaion={this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} from the renderList since it start giving warnings and the PlaceOrder.js screen beacme the first screen seen in app. I had kept the `const renderList = ((item) =>{
    return <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('PlaceOrder')} 
                activeOpacity={0.7}>
                <NearbyLSP name={item.name}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>` as it is in the 'HomeScreen.js' but the error remains

Comment: The code within the FlatList  of 'HomeScreen.js' is as follows `<FlatList
                                        data={data}
                                        renderItem={({item})=>{
                                            return renderList(item)
                                        }}
                                        keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
                                        
                                    />`